# Ruby on Rails - setting specific path to directory in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am attempting to implement Trumbowyg emojis plugin in my ruby on rails application. So I have referred to the below link for guidance on how to implement the plugin.

https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/blob/master/examples/plugins/emoji.html

```
          $('#editor').trumbowyg({
            btns: [['emoji']]
          });
          function initEmoji() {
            emojify.setConfig({
              img_dir : '../../bower_components/emojify.js/dist/images/basic/',
            });
            emojify.run();  
          }
          $('.trumbowyg-editor').bind('input propertychange', function() {
            initEmoji();
          });
          initEmoji();
```

How do I store the images in a directory and make reference to the directory under img_dir (as shown above) in a rails app?

Comment: Where do the emojis end up after running through the asset pipeline?

Comment: what I did was to place the png files in a folder called emojis which i placed in the app folder of my rails app. When i set the img_dir to be **img_dir : "<%= Rails.root.join('app', 'emojis') %>"** , i end up with the following error in console **GET http://localhost:3000/Users/kendrick/Desktop/work/working_hantly/mvp/app/emojis/japanese_ogre.png 404 (Not Found)** @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1: Embedding into Asset Pipeline

Without knowing exactly how this Javascript library works, the image path needs to be added to the Asset Pipeline.  Otherwise `rake assets:precompile` will not include all of the emoji images in the manifest file it generates and will not know how to serve those assets in the production environment (assuming default Production environment configuration).

See #config/initializers/assets.rb

```
# Add additional assets to the asset load path
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'emoji', 'image', 'directory')
```

## Option 2: Serve static images from `/public`

Another option is to not serve these files from the Asset Pipeline at all.  It may be too much trouble to coerce the Asset Pipeline into serving these assets correctly without modifying the Javascript library to use `asset-url` in all the JS and CSS files.

Instead, copy the files to a directory under `/public` so the Rails app can serve them.  Then adjust the `img_dir` in your Javascript configuration to be the path where the files are in /public.  Ex: `/emoji_images` if you put the files in `/public/emoji_images`.

Depending on how you're hosting the app, you may have to configure `serve_static_files` in `config/environments/production.rb`.